# Does laravel transactions has any memory/query's limit?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have one strange problem with laravel transactions

```
DB::transaction(function() {

     //Some operations
     // Around 200000  insert statements here 
});
```

The Problem is i'am getting only around 20000(this number was random not same every time) records on mysql. No errors in laravel logs, apache logs, mysql logs.

Please guide me in right direction. I know this was not a good approach but it was existing code i can't change now.

Running on web with potential timeouts
Php time out - 0,
mysql query timeout 600000

Using:Laravel - 5.2,
PHP - 5.6,
Mysql - 5.7.17

Comment: Are you running this through the web? (with potential timeouts) or as an artisan command?

Comment: In web only with (potential timeouts)

Comment: Then timeout is your most likely cause.... large volume data jobs are best done as back-end processes

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using chunks of inserts.

```
$insertArray = []; // you know, with 200,000 rows

DB::transaction(function() {
    foreach(array_chunk($insertArray, 2000) as $chunkInsert) {
        Modal::insert($chunkInsert); // this array is of size 2000
    }
});
```

Also, make sure that your *some operations* are **optimized** and if that has nothing to do with CRUD queries, then I suggest to write that code before the db::transaction.